# Which surah can help me get out of my depression

Tags: helping, blessings-of-allah, depression

Assalamualaikum.A few days ago I came to know my term final result and since then I am in great depression.I just can't get the result and my failure out of my head.This sort of things happened with me a year before but I somehow managed myself not getting into the acuteness of it by communicating with my friends and cousins.But this time it's worsening with every passing day because I am under lockdown since past 2/3 months.i am not even able to catch up on a sound sleep for almost 4 days.Would you please suggest me anything  any surah or Hadith or anything to get rid of my current condition?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamalaikum
I wish you would be better soon but bro everything will pass soon and somehow you will forget those bad things and I wish this period of time pass quickly and don't effect on you, There's no doubt that the best Suruh to remove your depression is Suruh Yusuf what a wonderful Suruh and I wich you will understand the lessons from this Suruh and how prophet Yusuf passed through bad things and then he became the Dear of Egypt

Answer (score 0):

A popular suggestion and a Surah that was revealed to the Prophet (AS) during a time that he had not received a revelation in a long while and started feeling as though Allah (SWT) had forsaken him, is `Surat Al-Duha`.

Here is also a very beneficial video from Ustadh Nouman Ali Khan regarding your situation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8TUTn5UBSw